# How to make multi-column unique constraints at the database level in web2py?

Tags: web2py

If I have something like this in my `models/db.py`:

```
   db.define_table('magazine', Field('name'), Field('description'))
   db.define_table('subscribe', Field('subscriber', db.auth_user), Field('magazine', db.magazine))
```

And in `controller/default.py`:

```
# subscribe callback from view
@auth.requires_login()
def subscribe():
    mag_id = request.args(0, cast=int)
    db.subscribe.insert(magazine=mag_id, subscriber=auth.user.id)
```

A user would click on a subscribe button which should call the callback and insert the user into the subscribe table with the current magazine he's viewing.

How would I make the subscribe table contain unique combinations of a subscriber and a magazine? A subscriber who has subscribed to a magazine should not be able subscribe to that same magazine again.

For example, this should work:

User 1, Magazine 1 
User 1, Magazine 2 
User 2, Magazine 1

But this should not:

User 1, Magazine 1
User 1, Magazine 1

One solution was the manually check if the combination already exists inside my controller:

```
def subscribe():
    mag_id = request.args(0, cast=int)
    subscribed = db(db.subscribe.subscriber==auth.user.id)&(db.subscribe.magazine==mag_id))

    if len(subscribed) < 1:
        # Do insert
    else:
        # Do nothing, user is already subscribed.
```

But is there a better way (preferably at the database level) to do this? I read using `IS_NOT_IN_DB()` could work, but it seems to be restricted to using forms? [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/web2py/yq9o3j-8C68) also suggests that it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAL doesn't provide a way for specifying a multi-column uniqueness constraint in the database, but you can do that directly in the database outside of web2py. However, you probably still want some explicit code in the application to handle this -- otherwise a violation at the database level will just end up generating an exception. In this case, you can simply use the [`.update_or_insert()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#update_or_insert) method:

```
db.subscribe.update_or_insert(magazine=mag_id, subscriber=auth.user.id)
```

That will only make the insert if a record with that magazine and subscriber does not already exist.

Comment: Oh, that's very handy. Thank you, that will probably do the trick.